# Filtering dates in Access queries?

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm building a report for a client. The report is not very complicated, just shows a bunch of stuff requested by the clients. One of the things I'm stuck on is... I need to be able to search by Transaction that took place between today and 6 months back. So when user click on Transaction report, it only shows the last 6 months from today. Anyone have any idea? I'm trying to build a query with that criteria, but I have no idea how it should be.

Another part of the report lets the client choose dates for the report (FROM & TO) and that's not too bad because I'm passing these values to a blank form and then using them in the report. However, here I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: Have you considered the [DateAdd Function](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19)?  Check whether `DateAdd("m", -6, Date())` gives you the oldest date you want included in the report.

Comment: Thank @HansUp I just did some research and was looking into this, but since I've never done it before, I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: it's not working. I'm building a query with this and for the TransactionDate field I added a WHERE and under criteria wrote this   DateAdd("m", -6,Now())                                                                                           this is from SQL                                                                            WHERE (((dbo_tblInv.InvTransDate)= DateAdd("m",-6,Now()))) NO ERROR, just didn't show any data. When i used DATE() instead of Now(), it only showed one record, but supposed to show over 25.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on, Barry.  What do you get with this?  `WHERE dbo_tblInv.InvTransDate >= DateAdd("m",-6,Date())`

Comment: Yup, that fixed the problem. Thank you very much HansUp!

Comment: the solution is >=DateAdd("m", -6, Date()).

Answer (score 1):

> =DateAdd("m", -6, Date()) This fulfills the requirements in my application